# MVVM Design with struct and async response

Tags: swift, mvvm, struct

I'm trying to implement the MVVM approach to my app and have some trouble with the required struct as Model. In a struct it is hard to manipulate its own data but I need two because its holds the view data.
I request data from a firebase database and after receiving, assigning the data to an array.
As I found out, I can not manipulate the array inside a response closure. When I try to call another function as callback I get the following error:
Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed

Here is my code:

```
 mutating func searchLocations(name: String, onlyOwnList: Bool) {
        if  onlyOwnList{
            onlineDataManager.getOwnLocations(searchName: name, userId: appViewModel.currentUser, completionHandler: getLocationsCallback)
        }
        else{
            onlineDataManager.getAvailableLocations(searchName: name,  userId: appViewModel.currentUser, completionHandler: getLocationsCallback)
        }
    }

mutating private func getLocationsCallback(_ locations: BarLocations){
        self.locationList.locations.removeAll()
        
        for location in locations.locations{
            self.locationList.locations.append(location)
        }
    }
```

I'm used to Java so im struggling with the sense of structs.
I hope somebody can help me or tell me, how to do it better

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're facing is that the mutation of the struct needs to happen in the same scope of the first `mutating` function since structs are pass-by-values.

```
 mutating func searchLocations(name: String, onlyOwnList: Bool) {
        if  onlyOwnList{
            onlineDataManager.getOwnLocations(searchName: name, userId: appViewModel.currentUser) { [weak self] locations in
                self?.locationList.locations = locations
            }
        } else{
            onlineDataManager.getAvailableLocations(searchName: name,  userId: appViewModel.currentUser) { [weak self] locations in
                self?.locationList.locations = locations
            }
        }
    }
```

To be honest, if your model is handling the loading of its own information, I'd change your model to be a class and not a struct. Either that, or handle the data load outside of the model (in your view controller and then create a simple struct with the information).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To work with a class was my first approach. But whe doing this, the Publish Function seems not to work. The ViewModel as a Publish Attribute on the instant of the Model but it’s not updating. 
Do you know what to do to get this work?

Comment: Ahh gotcha… I haven’t had much experience with publishers so I can’t quite say :/